# dynamic route code splitting check if module is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I problem with code splitting is that, if the module is big, the very first time the user will see a blank screen and delay.

```
    function errorLoading(err) {
      console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err);
    }

    function loadRoute(cb) {
      return (module) => cb(null, module.default); // I can't find any flag here
    }

    const routes = {
      component: App,
      childRoutes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          getComponent(location, cb) {
            System.import('pages/Home')
              .then(loadRoute(cb))
              .catch(errorLoading);
          }
        }
      ]
    };

export default () => <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />;
```

Here's a working example using code splitting base on dynamic route.

https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/react-dynamic-route-loading-es6/blob/master/client/pages/routes.js

How can I check if the module is loaded or not? I have to put a loading indicator.

Comment: Generally for this, my recommendation isn't "check if it is loaded", it is "if it hasn't rendered in X ms, show a spinner. Is that something that would work for you?

Comment: @loganfsmyth there's no flag to check that, that's my problem. ur suggestion is use setinterval to check?

Answer (score 0):

To make this working you will need to dynamically load bundle in the component code instead of `getComponent` hook.

In my app a have a component called `LazyComponent` that dynamically loads bundle when it is needed. Also, it allows you to display something while your big bundle is loading:

```
class LazyComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     this.state = {Component: null};
     super();
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     const pageName = this.props.location.params.page;
     System.import(`pages/${pageName}.js`).then(
       Component => this.setState({Component}),
       error => this.setState({error})
     )
   }

   render() {
     const { Component, error } = this.state;

     // render error message when bundle has failed to load
     if(error) {
       return <div>{error.message}</dib>
     }

     // render loader while component is not ready 
     if(!Component) {
       return <div>Loading...</div>
     }

     // render the component itself 
     return <Component {...this.props} />

   }
}
```

Then you can put this component into your routes definition

```
const routes = {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: LazyComponent
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: wow mind blown! didn't know I can use System import in another component. but is there any limitation for this approach?

Comment: I have been using this for the last 2 month in the app, that I am currently working on. So far haven't got any limitations